# Copy directory to a remote machine using SFTP in java

Tags: java, sftp

I need to copy a directory from my local machine to a remote machine via `SFTP`. I've done copying a file through `JSCH API`, but it doesn't work on directories. Any suggestions?

**I'm using the following code:**

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    String filename = localFile.getName();
    com.jcraft.jsch.Session sftpsession = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
    sftpsession.setUserInfo(new HardcodedUserInfo(password));
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    sftpsession.setConfig(config);
    sftpsession.connect();
    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp)sftpsession.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    channel.cd(remoteDirectory);
    channel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile), filename);
    channel.disconnect();
    sftpsession.disconnect();
```

Comment: I don't know how JSCH API is supposed to work, but one thing you can do is check if the file is a directory and, in that case, get all the files inside and send them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

JSCH doesn't have a single function to recursively send or receive a directory through SFTP. Your code will have to build the list of files and directories to be created on the remote system, then call `ChannelSftp.mkdir()` and `ChannelSftp.put()` to create the directories and files.

Also remember that you need to create parent directories before you create subdirectories. For example, `mkdir("/foo/bar/baz")` will fail if directory `/foo/bar` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy folder recursively on remote server using [JSCH java API](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Below is the sample code example for the same -

```
private static void recursiveFolderUpload(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {

    File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
    if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

        // copy if it is a file
        channelSftp.cd(destinationPath);
        if (!sourceFile.getName().startsWith("."))
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);

    } else {

        System.out.println("inside else " + sourceFile.getName());
        File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();

        if (files != null && !sourceFile.getName().startsWith(".")) {

            channelSftp.cd(destinationPath);
            SftpATTRS attrs = null;

            // check if the directory is already existing
            try {
                attrs = channelSftp.stat(destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName() + " not found");
            }

            // else create a directory
            if (attrs != null) {
                System.out.println("Directory exists IsDir=" + attrs.isDir());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Creating dir " + sourceFile.getName());
                channelSftp.mkdir(sourceFile.getName());
            }

            for (File f: files) {
                recursiveFolderUpload(f.getAbsolutePath(), destinationPath + "/" + sourceFile.getName());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**You can refer link [here](https://kodehelp.com/java-program-uploading-folder-content-recursively-from-local-to-sftp-server/) for more details on this code.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to copy a directory:

```
copy(File localFile, String destPath, ChannelSftp clientChannel)
{
    if (localFile.isDirectory()) {
        clientChannel.mkdir(localFile.getName());
        System.out.println("Created Folder: " + localFile.getName() + " in " + destPath);

        destPath = destPath + "/" + localFile.getName();
        clientChannel.cd(destPath);

        for (File file : localFile.listFiles()) {
            copy(file, destPath, clientChannel);
        }

        clientChannel.cd(destPath.substring(0, destPath.lastIndexOf('/')));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Copying File: " + localFile.getName() + " to " + destPath);
        clientChannel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile), localFile.getName(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
    }
}
```